# Problema DATE_FORMAT MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy trabajando con MYSQL, tengo una consulta muy simple, en donde muestro información para una lista de solicitudes. El problema que tengo es al mostrar la fecha y hora en que se creo la solicitud. Si reviso en la base de datos las fechas y horas guardadas están correctas pero al realizar la query ocupando DATE_FORMAT para que el formato en que muestre la fecha sea dd/mm/aaaa y no aaaa/mm/dd, se produce un error en la hora que muestra en la lista.

Ejemplo: una solicitud se creo el día 01-01-2022 **10:12:00** ,pero me muestra 01-01-2022 **10:05:20**. Al eliminar DATE_FORMAT se soluciona el problema. Espero que alguien me pueda orientar o indicar que estoy haciendo mal.

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

```sql
SELECT
    f.id_formulario_1,
    f.oficio, 
    DATE_FORMAT(f.fecha_solicitud, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%m:%s') AS fecha_solicitud,
    a.nombre AS nombre_asignatura,
    t.nombre_practica AS nombre_practica,
    f.n_total
    f.n_de_alumnos,
    dd_mm_inicio,
    DATE_FORMAT(f.dd_mm_inicio, '%d-%m-%Y') AS inicio,
    DATE_FORMAT(f.dd_mm_termino, '%d-%m-%Y') AS dd_mm_termino,
    f.hora_entrada,
    f.hora_salida,
    f.cupos_aprobados, 
    f.observaciones,
    f.respuesta,
    f.estado_solicitud
FROM
    servicio f
INNER JOIN asignatura a ON
    f.id_asignatura = a.id
INNER JOIN tipo_practica t ON
    f.tipo_practica = t.id
WHERE
    f.estatus = 1
ORDER BY
    id_formulario_1
```

Comment: Chequeaste que el tipo de dato en la base es DATETIME?

Comment: No, es Varchar (50)

Comment: Ahí esta el problema entonces, deberías convertirla a DATETIME para que DATE_FORMAT funcione correctamente.

Comment: Hice el cambio a DATETIME pero sigue ocurriendo lo mismo

Comment: intenta con ``DATE_FORMAT(f.fechaING, '%d-%m-%Y %T')``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero es verificar que nuestro tipo de dato corresponde a DATETIME en la base de datos, de lo contrario es posible que tengamos algún problema con datos registrados que no corresponden a una cadena de tiempo.
En caso de que la cadena no sea DATETIME, hay que convertirla a ese formato, tomando las precauciones del caso, verificar que tenemos respaldo de la base o hacer una copia de la columna para luego eliminar la original y reemplazarla por la copia ya formateada.

En tu caso el problema radica en que %m se usa para mostrar el mes, para mostrar los minutos es %i, o en su defecto debes usar %T para mostrar la cadena completa de hora minutos y segundos.

adjunto tabla con detalle:

```
Format  Description
%a      Abbreviated weekday name (Sun to Sat)
%b      Abbreviated month name (Jan to Dec)
%c      Numeric month name (0 to 12)
%D      Day of the month as a numeric value, followed by suffix (1st, 2nd, 3rd, ...)
%d      Day of the month as a numeric value (01 to 31)
%e      Day of the month as a numeric value (0 to 31)
%f      Microseconds (000000 to 999999)
%H      Hour (00 to 23)
%h      Hour (00 to 12)
%I      Hour (00 to 12)
%i      Minutes (00 to 59)
%j      Day of the year (001 to 366)
%k      Hour (0 to 23)
%l      Hour (1 to 12)
%M      Month name in full (January to December)
%m      Month name as a numeric value (00 to 12)
%p      AM or PM
%r      Time in 12 hour AM or PM format (hh:mm:ss AM/PM)
%S      Seconds (00 to 59)
%s      Seconds (00 to 59)
%T      Time in 24 hour format (hh:mm:ss)
%U      Week where Sunday is the first day of the week (00 to 53)
%u      Week where Monday is the first day of the week (00 to 53)
%V      Week where Sunday is the first day of the week (01 to 53). Used with %X
%v      Week where Monday is the first day of the week (01 to 53). Used with %x
%W      Weekday name in full (Sunday to Saturday)
%w      Day of the week where Sunday=0 and Saturday=6
%X      Year for the week where Sunday is the first day of the week. Used with %V
%x      Year for the week where Monday is the first day of the week. Used with %v
%Y      Year as a numeric, 4-digit value
%y      Year as a numeric, 2-digit value
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, cambie %m por %i, y se soluciono el problema.

Comment: Excelente, saludos.